# C#( Mono ) managed vs unmanaged arrays: benchmark favours managed?

Tags: c#, arrays, mono, benchmarking, unsafe

Benchmarking the following surprisingly gives better results for managed arrays( 10% faster, consistently ). I'm testing in Unity, so maybe it relates to Mono?

```
unsafe void Bench()
{
    //Locals
    int i, j;
    const int   bufSize         = 1024 * 1024;
    const int   numIterations   = 1000;
    const float gain            = 1.6745f;

    float[] managedBuffer;

    IntPtr  ptr;
    float * unmanagedBuffer;

    Stopwatch stopwatch; 

    // Allocations
    managedBuffer = new float[ bufSize ];
    for( i = 0; i < bufSize; i++ )
    {
        managedBuffer[ i ] = UnityEngine.Random.value;
    }

    ptr             = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( bufSize * sizeof( float ) );
    unmanagedBuffer = ( float * )ptr.ToPointer();

    Marshal.Copy( managedBuffer, 0, ptr, bufSize );

    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    // Unmanaged array iterations
    for( i = 0; i < numIterations; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < bufSize; j++ )
        {
            unmanagedBuffer[ j ] *= gain;
        }
    }

    UnityEngine.Debug.Log( stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds );

    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();

    // Managed array iterations
    for( i = 0; i < numIterations; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < bufSize; j++ )
        {
            managedBuffer[ j ] *= gain;
        }
    }

    UnityEngine.Debug.Log( stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds );

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal( ptr );
}
```

I'm experimenting with unsafe code for an audio application which is quite performance critical. I'm hoping to increase performance and decrease / eliminate garbage collection.

Any insights appreciated!

Comment: Benchmarking is a tricky art, easy to make mistakes and very small differences in the machine code can be noticeable.  Differences less than 15% are not statistically relevant.   Call this code at least 10 times, lower *numIterations* so you don't have to wait so long.  Note the significant variation in the results.  When I try it on .NET, code runs at the same speed.  As it should.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but needs more space than comment.

If you use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to observe IL code, then difference is (release, default settings, my PC: Windows 7 64):

```
        // unmanaged        
        IL_005a: ldloc.s unmanagedBuffer
        IL_005c: ldloc.1
        IL_005d: conv.i
        IL_005e: ldc.i4.4
        IL_005f: mul
        IL_0060: add
        IL_0061: dup
        IL_0062: ldind.r4
        IL_0063: ldc.r4 1.6745
        IL_0068: mul
        IL_0069: stind.r4
        IL_006a: ldloc.1
        IL_006b: ldc.i4.1
        IL_006c: add
        IL_006d: stloc.1

        // managed
        IL_00a4: ldloc.2
        IL_00a5: ldloc.1
        IL_00a6: ldelema [mscorlib]System.Single
        IL_00ab: dup
        IL_00ac: ldobj [mscorlib]System.Single
        IL_00b1: ldc.r4 1.6745
        IL_00b6: mul
        IL_00b7: stobj [mscorlib]System.Single
        IL_00bc: ldloc.1
        IL_00bd: ldc.i4.1
        IL_00be: add
        IL_00bf: stloc.1
```

I don't know how much machine code correspond to each IL instruction, but it might be optimization problem (see how much work required to calculate index in case of unmanaged buffer).

---

I noticed non-linear correlation between number of iterations and time:

[image]

First column is `numIterations`, second is unamanged time (ms), last one - managed time (ms).

Until `170` it's linear and then something start happening (disregards of increment, on screen is `10`, I tried `5` it's also good until `170`). This bugs me and I'd really want to get real answer here.

Comment: Just tried pointer arithmetics instead of indexer when iterating over the unmanaged array, it's even worse...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I need space.
Using C# nad VS13 I saw different assembly for multiplication.

**UNMANAGED**

```
00007FFC013555D9  movsxd      rcx,dword ptr [rbp+0D8h]  
00007FFC013555E0  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+0C0h]  
00007FFC013555E7  lea         rax,[rax+rcx*4]  
00007FFC013555EB  mov         qword ptr [rbp+50h],rax  
00007FFC013555EF  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
00007FFC013555F3  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [7FFC013558A0h]  
00007FFC013555FB  mulss       xmm0,dword ptr [rax]  
00007FFC013555FF  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
00007FFC01355603  movss       dword ptr [rax],xmm0
```

**MANAGED**

```
00007FFC01355722  movsxd      rcx,dword ptr [rbp+0D8h]  
00007FFC01355729  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+0D0h]  
00007FFC01355730  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+8]  
00007FFC01355734  mov         qword ptr [rbp+78h],rcx  
00007FFC01355738  cmp         qword ptr [rbp+78h],rax  
00007FFC0135573C  jae         00007FFC01355748  
00007FFC0135573E  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+78h]  
00007FFC01355742  mov         qword ptr [rbp+78h],rax  
00007FFC01355746  jmp         00007FFC0135574D  
00007FFC01355748  call        00007FFC60E86590  
00007FFC0135574D  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+0D0h]  
00007FFC01355754  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+78h]  
00007FFC01355758  lea         rax,[rcx+rax*4+10h]  
00007FFC0135575D  mov         qword ptr [rbp+80h],rax  
00007FFC01355764  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+80h]  
00007FFC0135576B  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [7FFC013558A0h]  
00007FFC01355773  mulss       xmm0,dword ptr [rax]  
00007FFC01355777  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+80h]  
00007FFC0135577E  movss       dword ptr [rax],xmm0
```

Obviously the big the code the slow the execution...